# POST complex parameters To REST service, Can I use a mock form submission

Tags: json, rest, resteasy

I recently asked this question:
[Question I asked recently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38401820/post-complex-parameters-to-rest-service-what-would-request-url-and-body-look-lik)

I like the restful way that link is represented BTW.  The question was essentially how do I get complex parameters to my REST service?  What would the code and parameters of that code look like?  Well, the more I thought about it, the more it reminded me of a simple a web form submission.  Keep in mind that the clients of this service are going to be native applications.  Why can't the client applications assemble the variables in questions into a post request Key-value object (including a byte array-file), bundle that and send it to my service where the appropriate action/response will occur?  Pretty sure that Java (RESTEasy is the framework I am using) can handle the request gracefully.  Am I crazy or has this already been worked out?

As an example of how this would look does anybody have a sample HTML string that would represent a simple post of a couple of variables, like this?

```
{
  "restriction-type": "boolean-search-restriction",
  "boolean-logic": "and",
  "restrictions": [
    {
      "restriction-type": "property-search-restriction",
      "property": {
        "name": "name",
        "type": "STRING"
      },
      "match-mode": "EXACTLY_MATCHES",
      "value": "admin"
    },
    {
      "restriction-type": "property-search-restriction",
      "property": {
        "name": "email",
        "type": "STRING"
      },
      "match-mode": "EXACTLY_MATCHES",
      "value": "admin@example.com"
    }
  ]
}
```

But with html headers and all???  I got that example from here btw:
[example JSON post](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/CROWDDEV/JSON+Requests+and+Responses)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `RestEasy` framework already provides a `JAX-RS client` implementation unless if you want to start from scratch using `HttpURLConnection` or even `HttpClient` from `Apache HttpComponents`.
Anyhow as long as the question is related to RESTEasy I will provide an example on the latter framework.

If the post looks like this :

```
@Path("/client")
public class ClientResource {

        @POST
        @Consumes("application/json")
        @Produces("application/json")
        public Response addClient(Client aClient) {
                String addMessage=clientService.save(aClient);
                return Response.status(201).entity(addMessage).build();
        }
        ...
}
```

A basic`RestEasy Client` call would look like this :

```
    public void testClientPost() {

        try {

            ClientRequest request = new ClientRequest(
                    "http://localhost:8080/RestService/client");
            request.accept("application/json");
            Client client=new Client(5,"name","login","password"); 
            //convert your object to json with Google gson 
            //https://github.com/google/gson
            String input = gson.toJson(client);
            request.body("application/json", input);
            ClientResponse<String> response = request.post(String.class);
            if (response.getStatus() != 201) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                        + response.getStatus());
            }
            //this is used to read the response.
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    new ByteArrayInputStream(response.getEntity().getBytes())));

            String output;
            System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
            while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(output);
            }

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```